# Signalr with redis backplane, sending message to user

Tags: .net-core, redis, signalr, asp.net-core-5.0

I am researching to use signalr to send messages from an api to a specific user (keyword).  Locally, I have everything working as designed (even using redis backplane).

When I move up to an actual environment with multiple servers (azure app service), it seems like messages to specific users don't flow through the backplane.  If I send a message to Clients.All it works.  But, if I send a message to Clients.User(username), the message is never received.  This works locally because it's a single server, but doesn't seem to work in multiple servers.

```
await this.impersonationContext.Clients.User(mainUserName).SendAsync("msguser", new object[] { mainUserName });
await this.impersonationContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("msg", new object[] { "wtf" });
```

If I call the above code, only the msg event is fired, but the msguser is never recieved.

Could I be missing something on the setup?  That's my assumption, I cannot be the only one doing this.

Below is my setup in the startup.cs.  This is using .net core 5 with the latest nugets, etc

```
services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        })
        .AddStackExchangeRedis(this.Configuration["Redis:Cache"], options => {
            options.Configuration.ChannelPrefix = "ImpersonationService";
        });
services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update #1
Looks like the user info is being pushed through the backplane (username hidden).  So maybe its the connection from javascript client?
[image]

Update #2
Getting closer...looks like the subscription isn't setup for the specific user like I see locally.  Could this be websockets?
[image]

Update #3
Found it....sorta.
I was missing the authorize attribute on the hub, which was allowing the websocket to connect, even though websockets isn't authenticating for some reason (different issue).  Once I added the authorize, it will drop down to long polling with the user info and works as designed